# Yii2 - Error whilst trying to save to the database

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables: Post and Comment. I have rendered the /comment/_form.php in /post/view.php. However when I try to add a comment I get the following error:

"The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `comment` (`body`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('First blog post', 3, '1499082140', '1499082140')"

I have declared the foreign constraints using:

"ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT fk_comment_post_id FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id);"

I know the problem is coming from the field 'post_id' not being picked up. My question is what can I do in my comment controller to find the current post ID and then populate the database? I am new to Yii and Software Development in general so apologies if I have missed any information out or posted in the wrong place etc.

Any help/resources would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, would be appropriated to put the queries inside <code> tag. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this!
you must have to give post_id and that should be valid (i.e. it should be present as id in post table)

```
   INSERT INTO comment (post_id,body, user_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (here will be corresponding post id ,'First blog post', 3, '1499082140', '1499082140').
```

that is how it work with sql i am not aware of yii sorry if i have made any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

after make reletion tables POST and COMMENT reGenerate Model POST and COMMENT.

if you have error in make reletion use this code in mysql console

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE comment ADD CONSTRAINT fk_comment_post_id FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id);
```